# Using Select Helpers in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking to use dplyr to select only variables in my dataset that end in "500" exactly. That is, I do not want variables ending in 2500, 5500, or 1500. Just 500. I tried using `ends_with("500")`, but this includes the aforementioned variables ending in 2500, etc that I want to exclude.

I'm sure this is a very thing to do, but I am having trouble finding exactly what I want via google search.

Thanks!

Comment: No sample data, no sample code, please spend some time to make this question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269) (more refs: [mcve] and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info).

Comment: what do you mean with "ends in 500 exactly"? ' 2500'  does end in `500`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `matches` instead of `ends_with` as `ends_with` does a fixed match and it will match the 500 or 1500 etc.  Instead, if we use `matches`, there is flexibility in it i.e. can specify `\\D+` before the 500 that it matches non-digits (not clear without a reproducible example though)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     select(matches('\\D+500$'))
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain a little more what the call to "matches" means?

Comment: @Cettt basically, I want to include things that end in 500 but not 2500. It is a measure of distance, so I only want variables measured at 500 meters, not 2500 meters.

Comment: @ZanePatterson The `\\D+` matches one or more characters that are not a digit, followed by 500 at the end (`$`) of the string i.e. column names

Comment: @ZanePatterson if you can tell us what characters are the prefix before the digits part, it would be great in formulating the `matches`.  Here, I was just guessing that the non-numeric part followed by numeric part in column names

Comment: @ZanePatterson Do you have column names as `"500"` `"2500"`  or `"hello_500"`, `"hello_2500"`

Comment: Yes, there are such variables, but there are others such as  `hello_bye500` and `hello_bye2500`

Comment: @ZanePatterson doesn't matter

Comment: @ZanePatterson The code still works `df1 <- tibble(hello_500 = 1:3, hello_bye500 = 2:4, hello_2500 = 1:3, hello_bye2500 = 1:3)`

Comment: sorry, wasn't exactly sure what you were asking. I tested it and it seems to have worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ZanePatterson its okay.  The `\\D+` works in most cases except if you have some special characters.  i.e. why I was asking for the pattern